# How do I view how many approved and rejected edits were approved?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

So I'm talking about the user suggesting not the reviewer.

So for example I suggested 100 edits. I know for approved but what about for rejected? How do I find out how many suggested edits did I get rejected on?

Comment: Go to your [suggestions tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2804613/puretppc?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and click on any suggested edits you have. From there you [expand the reviewer/editor stats](http://i.stack.imgur.com/z6pES.png). Not sure if there is reputation requirement though.

Comment: @Antony It actually works. Thanks. Ugh I don't know why I didn't see it lol. Also, just curious what edit % rate is considered good? Lets say min 50 edits.

Comment: @Antony thanks! I actually missed that last part. Learned something new and added to the answer.

Comment: @puretppc There isn't a % rate. That would be primarily opinion based. Just make sure your edits are substantial, and are truly improving the post. Sometimes edits get rejected because of a race condition, or simply an oversight on the part of the reviewers, and it may not be your fault at all.

Comment: Oh ok my bad for asking.

Comment: @puretppc - I've seen a lot of your edits through the review queue; and almost all the ones I've seen have involved just changing the indentation of code. In most cases, it's not really improving the post, and there are other issues with the post that should be addressing at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check in your activity tab the suggestions tab. It shows all your suggested edits, including the rejected ones.

[image: Click here on any suggested edit]
[image: Click here on more]

Comment: All I see is just suggestions (280 total). I guess we need certain rep to see how many approve vs rejects?

Comment: @puretppc It doesn't show a count of approved vs rejected, but for each edit you can see if it's approved or rejected.

Comment: Oh yeah I found it now.